# Proving that the boolean prime ideal theorem does not hold in a permutation model

Tags: set-theory

In the following paper, Truss and Felgner establish the independance of the order extension principle from the boolean prime ideal theorem by constructing a permutation model.

When proving that BPIT does not hold in this model, they write suppose I is a prime ideal supported by a subalgebra A. Then we will show all atoms a of A are in I, a contradiction. I might be being silly, but why is this a contradiction?

*Felgner, U.; Truss, J. K.*, [**The independence of the prime ideal theorem from the order-extension principle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2586759), J. Symb. Log. 64, No. 1, 199-215 (1999). [ZBL0933.03062](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0933.03062).

Comment: I don't have the paper in front of me, but I guess that a prime ideal, in this context cannot be the entire algebra?

Comment: So the argument goes that our set of urelements is a boolean algebra B (with a linear ordering extending its partial ordering). Then the permutations are those that preserve the structure of B. 

Now, in our permutation model we look for a prime ideal I on B. Such an ideal would have a finite support A, and since the subalgebra generated by a finite set is finite, we can think of finite supports as being subalebras of B. Then the paper says that if all the atoms of A (A not being the entire algebra B, just a finite subalgebra) are in I, then there is a contradiction, but I don't see it?

Comment: I mean, if it contains a subalgebra, it contains $1$, no?

Comment: Ah ok, this is just me totally misunderstanding what a subalgebra is. So 1 in a subalgebra is not the upper bound of that subalgebra in the bigger algebra, but is in fact just normal 1?

Comment: I think so. They mention that the subalgebra *generated by* as disjunctive normal forms given by the elements of the generating set.